# Cierre inesperado antes de pedir datos

Tags: c

Encontrar la división de dos números de forma recursiva el ejecutable sólo  pregunta por el primer dígito y luego se cierra sin preguntar por el segundo dígito.

```
#include<stdio.h> 



int division (int a, int b);

int main (){

int   a, b;
printf("Digite el primer numero");
scanf("%d", a);
printf("Digite el segundo numero");
scanf("%d", b);

printf("la division es %d ",division(a, b));

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


 int division (int a, int b) {
 if(b > a) {
 return 0;
 }
 else {
 return division(a-b, b) + 1;
 }
 }
```

Comment: En serio, ya has publicado unas cuantas preguntas. ¿Tanto cuesta adaptarse a las normas del sitio? ¿Por qué pones el texto de la pregunta como comentario? ¿En serio crees que así es más legible? ¿De verdad?

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra aquí:

```
printf("Digite el primer numero");
scanf("%d", a);                      // <<---
printf("Digite el segundo numero");
scanf("%d", b);                      // <<---
```

Y el motivo es que `scanf` necesita que le pases **un puntero** ya que si no es imposible que pueda modificar tus variables.

Como C posee un tipado bastante debil, el compilador te mostrará, a lo sumo, una advertencia... pero el código resultante no es tan benévolo y los sistemas operativos modernos no toleran intromisiones en regiones de memoria que no te pertenecen.

Solución: Pasa punteros a `scanf`:

```
printf("Digite el primer numero");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Digite el segundo numero");
scanf("%d", &b);
```